# How to trigger an event in a visual force page from another page

Tags: javascript, events, salesforce, twilio, addeventlistener

I have a VisualForce page which has the following code:

VFPage1:

```js
<apex:page >
    <style>
        .hasMotif {
            margin : 0px;
        }
    </style>
    <apex:iframe src="https://mysamplewebpage">
    <script>
        function receiveMessage(event) {
        if(event.data.type === 'myevent') {

         **Perform specific actions**

        } 
    }
    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
</script>
</apex:page>
```

I want the event of type 'myevent' in VFPage1 to get triggered whenver a specific action occurs in the page "https://mysamplewebpage". The backend source code for the page "https://mysamplewebpage" is again a VisualForce script as shown below:

VFPage2: https://mysamplewebpage

```js
<apex:page controller="TwiMLPage"
  showheader="false"
  contentType="text/xml"
  >{! '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>' }
{!twiml}
</apex:page>
```

In simple, VFPage2 is a page that handles twilio incoming calls. Now, how can I trigger the event 'myevent' in VFPage1 from the page VFPage2 whenever the "Dial" verb in VFPage2 is invoked.
The controller for VFPage2 is shown below:

MyTwiMLController:

```js
public class MyTwiMLController {

  public MyTwiMLController() {}

  public String getTwiml() {
    TwilioTwiML.Response res = new TwilioTwiML.Response();
    res.append(new TwilioTwiML.Say('Hello, Monkey!'));
    res.append(
      new TwilioTwiML.Play('http://demo.twilio.com/hellomonkey/monkey.mp3'));
    res.append(new TwilioTwiML.Hangup());
    return res.toXML();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.postMessage()` to communicate between execution contexts (e.g. an `<iframe>` and the containing window). In your case, you would need to add a script to VFPage2:

```
window.top.postMessage({ type: 'myevent' });
```

However, note that this kind of communication is subject to the browser's same-origin policy; if VFPage1 and VFPage2 are served from different domains, you need to pass additional parameters. You can read more here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: @Safranka I am not able to add the code to VFPage2 since it of xml type and errors pop up. Any idea on how I could add this to VFPage2?